# ado.net multi-threading critical section identification

Tags: multithreading, ado.net, critical-section

I'm new to multi-threading and figuring out what is and is not a critical section is still a skill I am working on. In this example I have ADO.NET code in a multi-threaded environment and am not sure if I need to lock anything here or not. Like the "command.Parameters.AddRange(parms);" line. Do I need to worry about a thread adding parameters to another threads Parameters Collection?

```
    internal async Task ExecuteNonQueryAsync(string spName, SqlParameter[] parms, TransactionScopeOption tranScopeOpt = TransactionScopeOption.Required)
    {
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(tranScopeOpt, TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
        {
            try
            {
                using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connString))
                {
                    await connection.OpenAsync();
                    using (var command = new SqlCommand(spName, connection))
                    {
                        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        command.Parameters.AddRange(parms);
                        await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                        scope.Complete();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok, and what is the shared resource here? All objects are either local or only read. The `params` array looks to be the only thing that might be accessed in an other thread. But why should it? Ps: dont forget to set stored procedure name in the command object.

Comment: Based on your response, it would seem I understand the critical sections less than I thought. Probably better to post a more general question about identifying critical sections instead. Also, I passed the stored proc name to the command constructor so am alright there.